# Apache simple redirect not working

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all requests from my website to a subdir but it doesn't work. This thing is going to make me crazy and any help would be appreciate.

In conclusion, I want this :

- http://mywebsite/test or http://mywebsite/test42 or http://mywebsite/everything

to

- http://mywebmysite/mydir

Here is my rule :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydir/$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydir/
```

But it doesn't work... Apache doesn't redirect. What am I doing wrong??

Thank you,

Regards.

Comment: Try adding the passed argument to '/mydir'. Something like **RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydir/$1 [NC,L]** where NC flag indicates "no case" detection (upper or lowercase matching) and L indicates to stop processing rules afterwards (not required but good practice in the event you have other rules later on).

Answer (score 0):

First make sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are working. If .htaccess is not enabled, add AllowOverride All to Apache configuration file to enable .htaccess

For redirecting test

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?test/(.*)$ /mydir/$1 [R,L]`

or for everything

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydir/$1 [R,L]`